# How to convert invalid UUID string to valid UUID string

Tags: ios, swift

I am having string that i want to convert UUID

my string is - > "43pszizx-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

i want to convert this into UUID

i have tried this code

```
let contactUUID = "43pszizx-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

if let uuid = UUID(uuidString: contactUUID) {
            moviesVC.conversationID = uuid
        }
```

but it always returns  nil

is there any solution to convert this string to UUID, this string coming from API as a contactId

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you realise that the string itself is not a valid `UUID`? You just want to generate a `UUID` based on the string, right?

Comment: yes , i want  to generate UUID based on string

Comment: As @Sweeper pointed out the string isn't a valid UUID, and this is the reason why initialization of UUID fails: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid/3126814-init What do you want to do with a string representing a non-valid UUID?

Comment: Hi @lazarevzubov, i want a static UUID for each user, and it should not change

Comment: Ugh. You can't have a UUID from a string that is not a UUID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://Returns%20nil%20if%20the%20string%20isn%E2%80%99t%20a%20valid%20UUID%20representation.)

**Returns nil if the string isn’t a valid UUID representation.**

```
let contactUUID = "43pszizx-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
//The string representation of a UUID, such as E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F.
```

But the `contactUUID` doesn't seems to be matching with UUID representation so its always returning nil